# NSMenuItem setHidden doesnt work?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, hide, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I try to hide a `NSMenuItem` but the method doesn't work. My `NSMenuItem` is not nil (`-setTitle`, `-setEnabled` work as expected). Outlet is connected correctly in the IB and `-setAutoEnableItem` is set to NO.

But `[item setHidden:YES];` doesn't change anything. Do you have an idea how to hide a NSMenuItem?

To remove and add the item again is no option for me.

Comment: What `NSMenuItem` you are trying to hide? Your created or default? If your created item it should work with `-setHidden`.

Comment: I created this NSMenuItem by myself.

Comment: You created `NSMenu` and added in it `NSMenuItem`? or added item to existing menu?

Comment: i created a nsmenu by myself, and added multiple nsmenuitems to it. Both were created like this: IBOutlet NSMenu(NSMenuItem) *name; @property(assign) IBOutlet NSMenu(NSMenuItem) *name; @synthesize name=_name; and then connected in IB and released in dealloc

Comment: then i try to call [self.name setHidden:YES]; which doesnt work. but self.name is not nil and [self.name setTitle:@"Titel"]; works. Also if i set the Checkbox "Hidden" in IB it doesnt hide aswell....

Comment: Here i uploaded a Demo Project: http://cl.ly/I5Oy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMenuItem` hide problems are due to alternate items. If item have alternate item or items it can't be hidden. But You can solve it like this:

For example You want to hide *item2* with alternate items *itemAlt2* and *itemCtrl2*. So make *itemAlt2* and *itemCtrl2* not alternates and hidden like this:

```
[itemAlt2 setAlternate: NO];
[itemAlt2 setHidden: YES];
[itemCtrl2 setAlternate: NO];
[itemCtrl2 setHidden: YES];
[item2 setHidden: YES];
```

And when You need visible *item2* just make them alternate and visible like this:

```
[itemAlt2 setAlternate: YES];
[itemAlt2 setHidden: NO];
[itemCtrl2 setAlternate: YES];
[itemCtrl2 setHidden: NO];
[item2 setHidden: NO];
```